# What is the best word to describe someone who always anticipates things?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, epithet-requests

What is the best word to describe a person who always anticipates or thinks of future or possible things (occurrences) according to previous events;
i.e., who extrapolates to the consequences of current information,
when those consequences are not obvious to others.

Examples in home and work contexts:

- When he saw an excavation happening near his home,
  he anticipated that maybe the water line would be out and prepared for it.
- When he saw a news item about an event that happened,
  he realized his boss is in tune with these events
  and he anticipated how this would affect his boss's decisions and planning.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What is the context (e.g. financial, weather)? By *always*, do you mean that it's their job or their personality? Please edit your question to clarify what you're after. The [single-word-requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) tag information may be helpful for this.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest for 'anticipate'? And why were those not sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Do you want a verb like "anticipate," or an adjective like "precognizant," or a noun like "prophet"?

Answer (score 6):

The Cambridge English Dictionary defines [***far-sighted***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/far-sighted) as

> having good judgment about what will be needed in the future
> and making wise decisions based on this:
> *Buying those shares was a very far-sighted move –
> they must be worth ten times their original value now.*

They label this a “UK” definition, but I disagree. 
I’m a US person, and I believe that this meaning
would be well understood here. 
Note that these definitions of  ***farsighted*** 
(incidentally, not hyphenated):

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farsighted):
>
>   able to predict what will or might happen in the future
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/farsighted):
>
>   wise, as in foreseeing future developments:
>   *a farsighted statesman.*

carry no geographic restriction.

***Forward-looking*** has a similar meaning:

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forward-looking):
>
>   concerned with the future or planning for the future
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/forward-looking):
>
>   planning for or anticipating possible future events, conditions, etc.; 
>   progressive.

Words such as ***wise***, ***sensible***, ***sage***, ***sagacious***,
and ***perspicacious*** are listed as synonyms for the above:

> ***perspicacious***:
>   [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perspicacious):
>
>     quick in noticing, understanding, or judging things accurately:
>     *His perspicacious grandfather had bought the land as an investment,
>     guessing that there might be gold underground.*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspicacious):
>
>     having or showing an ability to notice and understand things
>     that are difficult or not obvious

Other suggested synonyms include ***intuitive***, ***prophetic***,
and ***psychic***, but I guess these are not what you want
(with the possible exception of ***intuitive***).

---

**Footnote:**
A more literal definition of ***farsighted***,
which is frequently listed as the primary definition
(especially when it is not hyphenated), is:

> [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/far-sighted):
>
> - long-sighted
>
>   able to see things clearly that are far away
>   but not things that are near you:
>   *I’m so far-sighted, I can’t read the newspaper without my glasses.*
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/farsighted):
>
> - seeing objects at a distance
>   more clearly than those near at hand; hyperopic.
>
>   seeing to a great distance.

The antonym of this sense of *farsighted* is ***nearsighted***:

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nearsighted):
>
>   unable to see things that are far away :
>   able to see things that are close more clearly
>   than things that are far away

while the antonym of the first sense is ***shortsighted***:

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortsighted):
>
>   not considering what will or might happen in the future;
>   lacking foresight

although some people use these terms interchangeably.  
(Both of these words (especially *shortsighted*) can be hyphenated.)

Comment: I disagree.  Farsighted, in m opinion, is when someone has difficulty seeing things close to their eyes..  Foresight is the right word.

Comment: @dockeryZ:  I see your opinion and raise you three dictionary definitions. What else do you have up your sleeve?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  If you want to submit ***foresighted*** (and/or ***foresightful***) as an answer, go ahead.  (Note that “lacking foresight” is included in the definition of ***shortsighted*** that I quoted.)

Answer (score 2):

Such a person would be called a *prognosticator*.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/prognosticator)

> one who predicts future events or developments

Comment: Yeah I like this answer better than mine.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reference?

Answer (score 2):

You can describe such a person as *[prescient](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/prescient)*:

> **prescient**, *adj.*: knowing or behaving as if you know what will happen in the future

Such as "Arthur C. Clarke is an author who wrote eerily *prescient* works of fiction."

Comment: I like it. Thanks! took 4 years to have this kind of answer. but yeah thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The person in question is likely a ***visionary***.

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/visionary):

> **visionary** *noun* [ C ] (ABLE TO IMAGINE THE FUTURE)
>
> a person who has the ability to imagine how a country, society,
> industry, etc. will develop in the future and to *plan* in a suitable
> way

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/visionary):

> *NOUN* (plural visionaries)
>
> A person with original ideas about what the future will or could be
> like:
>
> he is a visionary keen on policy-making
>
> The website boasts that ‘Freeness is the now, and tomorrow for future
> music visionaries.’
>
> She's written a book about space tourism, and
> talked to many of the visionaries behind the whole idea.
>
> We need more
> such hands-on visionaries for the future of York if we are to create
> and maintain a competitive position on the world stage.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visionary):

> **visionary**
> *noun*
>
> : a person who has clear ideas about what should happen or be done in
> the future
>
> : a person who has a powerful imagination
>
> 3 :  one having unusual foresight and imagination : a visionary in the
> computer industry
>
> She's a *visionary* in her field.
>
> Definition of visionary for Students  :  a person
> who has an exceptional ability to *plan* or have ideas for the future

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/visionary):

> *noun*, plural visionaries.
>
> 7. a person of unusually keen foresight.

Comment: My gut tells me that “visionary” is a grander term than what the OP wants. The question asks for a word for someone who is perceptive, intelligent, and capable of extrapolating from past and present events to anticipate future ones. I think of a visionary as someone who has great imagination; a person who can conceive of many possible futures and act in a way that influences the course of the future. However, your very extensive collection of references supports the suitability of your answer, so +1 … good job!

Answer (score 0):

Shrewd
Pragmatic  if we are talking about plans and effects on physical things
Considerate if we are talking about anticipating other people's feelings and emotions and influencing them for the better with kindness
Canny implies knowledge of cause and effect 
Astute implies observant 
Sensible
Judicious 
Practical connotes knowledge of effects on physical things
Politic like shrewd connotes knowledge of effects on the hearts and minds of others, and to a lesser extent the physical world

Some pejorative words below:
Calculating 
Manipulative
Cunning
crafty
Scheming
Artful

Answer (score 0):

A *prognosticator* is the word you are looking for I believe.

> To predict according to present indications or signs; foretell.

[Reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prognosticator)

Comment: (1) “prognosticator” is a good answer, IMO. Unfortunately, [it was already given four days earlier](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/338778/26083#338788). (2) You should probably clarify the fact that, while you’re talking about “prognosticator” and you’ve *linked to* a definition for “prognosticator”, you’re actually ***quoting** (citing)* a definition for “prognosticate”.

Comment: Well spotted @scott I hadn't realised this was given earlier, will remove my answer this evening once you've had a chance to read this comment ! I better go uv the original now:)

Answer (score -3):

Clairvoyant might be the word you're looking for.

> noun 1. a person who claims to have a supernatural ability to perceive
>   events in the future or beyond normal sensory contact.
>
> adjective 1. having or exhibiting an ability to perceive events in the
>   future or beyond normal sensory contact. "he didn't tell me about it
>   and I'm not clairvoyant"

Comment: It might be. Please explain your answer in full.

Answer (score -3):

How about an Harbinger, which is one who shows what is coming or will come.

Also, a strategist, which is a person who is always planning things and the things that will result of other things. For that one I would say "a strategist of sorts".

Not to mention an "harbinger of sorts".

Comment: Adding a dictionary definition of "harbinger" would show that a harbinger *heralds* an event, which is quite different to the OP's description of someone who *anticipates the consequences* of an event people are already aware of.